# Is $\Bbb Z_3$ a subset of $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I was told that this is not true. Based on my understanding of a subset it would seem that this is true.

If every element of $\Bbb Z_3$ is in $\Bbb Z$ then it is a subset. $0,1,2$ are in $\Bbb Z$, so is it not a subset?

Comment: Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ are typically congruence classes, not actual integers.

Comment: It is NOT because the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ are equivalence classes not just numbers. So when we say $0 \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ it means the class of $0$ which is the set $\{3k \, | \, k \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: @AnuragA Your comment is a nice little demonstration of the importance of commas. Right now it looks like a forceful rejection of Randall's comment.

Comment: It is better to think of $\Bbb Z_3$ as a quotient of $\Bbb Z$, not as a subset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really the right question to ask, since you could always take the underlying set of $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ to be some representative subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ (like $\{0,1,2\}$) and transfer addition and multiplication over, and then the underlying set of $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ would be a subset of the underlying set of $\mathbb{Z}$. (The standard definition, of course, is in terms of equivalence classes, but in practice we take such representatives when performing concrete calculations.)

What really matters for algebra is that $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ is not a *subring* of $\mathbb{Z}$. That is, no matter the particulars of how you actually define $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ using set theory, there is no injective function $f:\mathbb{Z}/(3)\to\mathbb{Z}$ that preserves the addition and multiplication operations.

Comment: what do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}/3$ ? I have not come across this in my studies and I had a hard time googling anything about it. A link would be appreciated